# build llvm : choose which components to build

Tags: cmake, llvm

I build LLVM with cmake, but I only need a specific set of components.
So, I don't need to build the full LLVM package and wish to restrict the build to what I need only.

By example, here is the list of components I use :

llvm_libs Analysis Core ExecutionEngine InstCombine Object RuntimeDyld ScalarOpts Support native mcjit mc mcdisassembler

Does someone has experience with this ? Because building everything take a long time :-(

Thx

Comment: If you build whole LLVM once, the next time `make` will build only the parts you modify code for. Also to speedup build process you can use mutli-threaded build by doing: `make -jN` , where N is the number of threads you want to use. Recommended value of N is `num_of_hardware_threads + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`make help` is your friend. There you can find a list of all targets and choose what you need. Most likely, `make LLVMAnalysis LLVMCore ...`